# Use javascript to test if one function is clicked/triggered, then disable the another function.

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, click, detect

I have function `a`:

```
$(document).ready(function a(){
        $('.c, .d').click(function() { 

            $("f").each(function(i) {
                c=i+1
                print c
    });
});
});
```

and I've function `b`:

```
$(document).ready(function b(){
       $("f").each(function(i) {
                c=i+1
                print c      
    });
});
```

I want to detect if the function `a` is clicked and triggered. then disable the function `b` , how to do that in javascript?

Comment: from what you have shared function b is executed on dom ready, before the user has any chance to click an element which could trigger the click handler in a... so I don't see a way to control the execution of `b`

Comment: function a and functionb are from two different files. i have no chance to make this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a declaration of `disable` outside the function scopes: `var disable = false;`, set this variable to `true` in function `a()` and check it in function `b()`. Like so:

`a.js`:

```
var disable = disable || false;

$(document).ready(function () {
    function a() {
        disable = true;

        $('.c, .d').click(function () { 
            $('f').each(function (i) {
                c = i + 1;
                // print c
            });
        });
    }
});
```

`b.js`:

```
var disable = disable || false;

$(document).ready(function () {
    function b() {
        if (typeof disable !== 'undefined' && disable)
            return;

        $('f').each(function (i) {
            c = i + 1;
            // print c      
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: hi,the problem is:function a and function b are not in same javescript files.i wonder if i seperate it in two files ,it will not work?

Comment: Aha, I have updated my suggestion. It should still work since `disable` is a global variable. :)

Comment: A tad bit uncertain of how you use `a()` and `b()` though.

Comment: hi see you set var disable = disable || false;  twice,will it conflict?

Comment: and the other way around,if function b in js.b is triggered/clicked,can i set function a in js.a disable?

Comment: hi,i test it doesnt work,when i click '.c, .d' in function a (js.a),still function b is enable.i guess it is because you run it after document ready?

Comment: Put the variable change in the click event if you want it to change when clicked, yes.

Comment: But as you have not provided a clear use case description it's hard to me to follow.

Answer (score 0):

If function a is called, add a line which stores some value in a form that indicates a was called:

```
(document).ready(function a(){
     document.forms.FunctionAForm.inputname.value = 'yes';
     $('.c, .d').click(function() { 

            $("f").each(function(i) {
                c=i+1
                print c
        });
    });
});
```

The modify function b as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function b(){
   if (document.forms.FunctionAForm.inputname.value === 'yes') {
       return false;
   } else {
       $("f").each(function(i) {
            c=i+1
            print c      
       });
   }
 });
```

The function does not execute since function a was already called, which has been stored
in the form.

Answer (score 0):

You can take one flag like active and make it true in your function A and check if it is true or not in function b like below

```
$(document).ready() {
var active = false;

function a(){
                active = true;
                $('.c, .d').click(function() { 

            $("f").each(function(i) {
                c=i+1
                print c      
              });
           }

function b(){
           if(!active)
           {
                 return;
           }
           $("f").each(function(i) {
                c=i+1
                print c      
           });
}
});
```